# Difference between ${scmBranch} and $\{scmBranch} for maven-jar-plugin/ maven-war-plugin

Tags: maven, syntax, maven-war-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I do use the maven-jar-plugin in my pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
         <manifestEntries>
            <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
            <SCM-Branch>${scmBranch}</SCM-Branch>
         </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Opening it with IntelliJ 
`${scmBranch}` I do get following message:
`"cannot resolve symbol 'scmBranch' .."`

Property `${buildNumber}` seems to be ok - no complaining here.

If I change `${scmBranch}` to `$\{scmBranch}` as in the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) error dissapear.

What is exactly the difference between stating a maven property as `${}` and `$\{}`?